# Type Initializer Error Thrown by linq2db InformixDataProvider when run in Web Application but not Console

Tags: c#, asp.net, informix, linq2db

I am trying to use the linq2db library (thanks by the way!) to retrieve records from an Informix database.  I followed the steps from the documentation and was able to successfully get records from an ASP.NET console applicaiton using the Visual Studio debugger.  However, I then tried to follow the same with a fresh and standalone ASP.NET MVC5 application and I am getting the error "The type initializer for 'IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDecimal' threw an exception." also running using Visual Studio debugger.  I did some digging by downloading the source code and adding some break points and found that Line 125 and line 133 of the file LinqToDB.DataProvider.Informix.InformixDataProvider file are involved in causing the error.  But that is as far as I got.  So running in the context of a web application throws an error, but running in a console application is fine.

below is line 125 of LinqToDB.DataProvider.Informix.InformixDataProvider

```
MappingSchema.AddScalarType(_ifxDecimal,  GetNullValue(_ifxDecimal),  true, DataType.Decimal);
```

below is the GetNullValue method in that class (lines 130 to 134 of same file), error gets thrown on **return getValue.Compile()()**

```
static object GetNullValue(Type type)
{
    var getValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Field(null, type, "Null"), typeof(object)));
    return getValue.Compile()();
}
```

**Additional Info..**
In the documentation titled Informix Client Software Development Kit (Version 4.10) in Table 2-1. Best-fit types for retrieving Informix data types it shows that there are three DECIMAL Informix types, each map to three different suggested .NET types

Comment: i found some time to continue my digging and thinking this may have something to do with Thread Culture ?? I also found that when drilling down through the error above the expression ((System.Exception)(((IBM.Data.Informix.IfxException)(((System.Exception)(typeInitializationException))._innerException)).Message))._message gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I would recommend you to create an issue (along with exception details and stack trace) here: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues

Comment: thank you nightcoder, this is done. i did not have time to add the full stack trace (i removed it from my solution for now).. here is the link.. https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/219

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't use Informix in partial trust environment. When I try to create IfxConnection in partial trust, I get SecurityException - 'That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.'

Comment: hi Igor. i am not sure if your claim that Informix cannot be used is correct because i am successfully using IBM.Db.Informix IfxConnection directly inside a new ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. I will try to send you a solution that has two projects - one with the working console app and another web mvc 5 app (that throws the error).. and maybe a third to show IfxConnection working.  I will send to your email.

Answer (score -1):

Too old to comment, but, I had this error too. Solved it placing `getValue.Compile()` in place of `getValue.Compile()();`.

Works fine now.